# CSS: How to make flex column layout grow on x-axis first?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a list of words to display on a page. It can be any size, with random number of letters. I want them to be arranged in columns, and to grow on width first instead of height first.

I tried doing it `flex`, maybe Iam wrong, here is what I have:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoNicolle/fa428qru/89/)

```js
function makeid(length) {
  let result = "";
  const characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  const charactersLength = characters.length;
  let counter = 0;
  while (counter < length) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    counter += 1;
  }
  return result;
}
const words = [];
new Array(200).fill(0).forEach((_, i) => {
  const length = 2 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
  words.push(makeid(length));
});


const wordsMap = words
  .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)
  .reduce((acc, word) => {
    if (acc[word.length]) {
      acc[word.length].push(word);
    } else {
      acc[word.length] = [word];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});

const wordsC = document.querySelector('.words')

Object.entries(wordsMap).forEach(([size, words]) => {
  [+size, ...words].forEach((w, i) => {
    const span = document.createElement('span')
    span.innerText = w;
    span.classList.add(i === 0 ? 'size' : 'word');
    wordsC.appendChild(span);
  })
})
```

```css
.page {
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1cm;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.words {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.size {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.word {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="body">
    <div class="words">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Edit:

I think I was not very clear, let me add more context:

So what I have now is on the left, what I need ison the right.
[image]

I want the words to take the less height as possible, and be arranged in columns. So as the list of words grows, it creates column first and a new row only when all the columns are full. Here is how it should behave:

[image]

While for now here is how it behaves: It creates a new column only when each rows are full:
[image]

- to add a sibling to the `.words` div, with a `flex:100;` to push the words on top: fail.
- To measure the remaining area in JS and adapt the height dinamically: fail

Any idea how I could do it with pure css ?

Comment: What is your goal here?

Comment: Hi, I would like the words to take the minimum height as possible by spreading over the maximum number of columns as possible. Here they do the reverse: they fill up the entire height of the container, and take only half of the width.

Comment: Hopefully my answer solves your problem. Check below.

Comment: Your images are not consistent so I’m struggling to understand what you want. (The number of lines in e.g. section 3 is not the same). What is the general algorithm to determine when the lines should start going horizontally rather than vertically? Or is this a one off case where we can assume the first one to be in one column, the second in two and the last is to fill at  the bottom as evenly as possible?

Comment: Hi Andre, yes sorry I thought it would be clearer like that. I have added a couple of more drawings and some more explainations. I think this time it cannot be unclear ;)

Answer (score 0):

The undesired behaviour that you are seeing is being done by this CSS rule:

```
.words{
  align-content: flex-start;
}
```

To make them take the whole width you have a range of options, among them `align-content: stretch;` or `align-content: space-evenly;`.
To change the your content vertically you can use the property `justify-content` in your flex container (.words). However, here the height and width are being set by:

```
.page{
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
}
```

Since your word can't fit the screen in one column they are wrapping, so they will wrap to fit the height pre-set by the rule above. Maybe shortening this height is also something you can consider.

Comment: Hi Andre ! Thanks for your response ! The thing is I am doing an export for printing, so the page height is given, cannot change. Same for the gap between columns, that's why I have `flex-start` + `gap`. I need some sort of a `max-height:fit-content` but with `wrap`.

Comment: Maybe add a sketch with your desired result, cause at the moment is quite unclear.

Comment: Okay  I adde a picture and refor;ulated a little. Sorry for being so unclear :)